# Timetable Web Scraping with multiple tables (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm just looking for some info regarding python web scraping. I'm trying to get all the data from [this](http://goo.gl/TOqrE) timetable and I want to have the class linked to the time its on at. Looking at the html there's multiple tables (tables within tables). I'm planning to use Google App Engine with Python (perhaps BeautifulSoup also). Any suggestions on the best way of going about this is?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I've managed to extract the required data from the table using the following code:

```
import urllib
from lxml import etree
import StringIO

url = "http://ttcache.dcu.ie/Reporting/Individual;Locations;id;lg25? 
template=location+Individual&weeks=20&days=1-5&periods=1-30&Width=0&Height=0"
result = urllib.urlopen(url)
html = result.read()

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(html), parser)

xpath = "//table[2]/tr/td//text()"

filtered_html = tree.xpath(xpath)

print filtered_html
```

But I'm getting a lot of these `u'\xa0', u'\xa0', '\r\n', '\r\n'` characters scattered throughout the parsed text. Any suggestions on how I could combat these?

Thanks

Comment: This is a really simple task you can to use lxml lib for it.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little please? I'm new to lxml so not sure where to start. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best library available for parsing HTML is lxml, which is based on libxml2. Although it's intended for XML parsing it also has a HTML parser that deals with tag soup far better than BeautifulSoup does. Due to the parser being in C it's also much much faster.

You'll also get access to XPath to query the HTML dom, with the libxml2 support for regular expression matches in XPaths which is very useful for web scraping.

libxml2 and lxml are very well supported and you'll find there are packages for them on all major distros. Google App engine appears to support it as well if you're using 2.7 https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

EDIT:

The characters you're getting are due to there being a lot of empty table cells on the page, so your xpath is often matching the whitespace characters (which are non-breaking spaces). You can skip those text nodes with no non-space characters with a regular expression something like this:

```
xpath = "//table[2]/tr/td//text()[re:match(., '\\S')]"

filtered_html = tree.xpath(
    xpath,
    namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})
```

The namespaces bit just tells lxml that you want to use it's regular expression extension.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you suggest any good links/tutorials that would be of benefit? I haven't used lxml before but it sounds interesting!

Comment: The best place to start is probably the documentation: http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html It has a bunch of examples showing how to do various things.

Comment: Thanks. Had a crack at it and I'm having a few problems, I've described them in an update above if you wouldn't mind having a look!

Comment: I've added some more info.

Comment: That solves the problem. Is there a way to link the lectures (i.e. each cell) to its specified time? I'm thinking those whitespaces could come in useful now. It's working nicely on app engine by the way, I just want to have the times linked with lectures to store in a datastore.

Comment: The nodes are returned as a list, you could potentially iterate over the time nodes and then run a second xpath for each one to get the related lectures.